# How to run multiple script using postscribe

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to execute script dynamically inside div using postscribe https://github.com/krux/postscribe/

Below is the code snippet

```
  <div id="searchBox1" style="float: left;">
    </div>
 <div id="searchBox2">
    </div>
```

Here is the script

```
 $.get("/api/service/Getscripts/", function (data) {


           postscribe('#searchBox1', data.script1, {
               done: function () {
                   console.log("1st success");

               },
               error: function () {
                   console.log("1st error");
               }
           });
           postscribe('#searchBox2', data.script2, {
               done: function () {
                   console.log("2nd success");
               },
               error: function () {
                   console.log("2nd error");
               }
           });

       });
```

The above code works only for the first script but it fails to render the 2nd one. Please suggest?